# MSBuild x86 - Silverlight 4 SDK not installed

Tags: silverlight-4.0, msbuild, windows-phone-7

My build server won't compile by Windows Phone 7 application giving the error "The Silverlight 4 SDK is not installed".

1. The SDK is installed and the registry entries exist under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsft\Microsoft SDKs\Sliverlight.
2. It's only a 32-bit machine anyway, but I've tried the /p:Platform=x86 solution without result.

Comment: This post has great details of using MSBuild for WP7: [TFS2010 WP7 Continuous Integration](http://justinangel.net/TFS2010WP7ContinuousIntegration) Also, check out his other article [Windows Phone 7 - Emulator Automation](http://justinangel.net/#BlogPost=WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a stupid question but did the WP7 sdk is installed ? Do you have this directoy on your build server:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone\

with the dlls like System, System.Net etc ?

Comment: That was it, for some reason it was in Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\WindowsPhone i.e. no Profile directory, so the targets file couldn't find them